# ¿Cómo intercambiar valores entre dos columnas de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, script

Se debe corregir un error de usuario en una tabla, para encontrar el error ejecute un query:

```
SELECT * FROM pos_order_line WHERE qty < -4000
```

y obtengo el resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es tomar el valor de la columna "qty" y el valor de la columna "price_unit" e intercambiarlos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede hacer eso en un solo query??

#### ::: Informacion de la tabla :::

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte la estructura de la tabla, de que tipo sonsus campos para poder ayudarte con una solución

Comment: @Rostan información agregada

Comment: Ya agregué una respuesta, faltaría que detalles cual es la clave primaria de la tabla para que coincida con lo que te pase.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente, crear una variable tipo tabla en la cuál cargarías los datos de tu tabla **pos_order_line**, luego de ello haces un **UPDATE** con joins de las claves primarias, esto es importante, en mi ejemplo lo hice asumiendo que tus claves primarias son **id** y **create_uid**, y listo.

```
--  Creas la variable
DECLARE @pos_order_line TABLE
(
    id integer,  --  PK (asumo)
    create_uid integer,  --  PK (asumo)
    price_unit numeric,
    qty numeric
)

--  Cargas la variable, con los registros que necesitas cambiar
INSERT INTO @pos_order_line(id, create_uid, price_unit, qty)
SELECT id, create_uid, price_unit, qty
FROM pos_order_line WHERE qty < -4000

--  Actualizas los registros únicamente cargados en la variable, 
--  por ello importante lo de las claves primarias
UPDATE A
SET A.price_unit = B.qty, A.qty = B.price_unit  --  actualizando
FROM @pos_order_line AS B
INNER JOIN pos_order_line AS A
    ON (A.id = B.id
        AND A.create_uid = B.create_uid)
```

Saludos.

Comment: La tabla tiene cientos de registros; pero solo quiero que el cambio afecte al lote que aparece en el query original.

Comment: SELECT * FROM pos_order_line WHERE qty < -4000

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta con la carga de la variable tipo tabla en base a los datos que vas a actualizar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un `UPDATE` a la tabla haciendo un `JOIN` consigo misma, lo cual permite "mantener" los valores para actualizar la segunda columna:

```
UPDATE pos_order_line t1, pos_order_line  t2 
    SET t1.price_unit=t1.qty, t1.qty=t2.price_unit 
    WHERE t1.id=t2.id 
          and t1.qty < -4000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres modificar solo es el orden, únicamente tienes que declarar en el select el orden de las columnas que quieres, como no se el nombre de tu tabla, hice la consulta con los nombre de las columnas que se pueden observar.

```
SELECT 
 id, create_uid, notice, create_date,
 product_id, order_id, qty, company_id, 
 price_unit,write_date, write_uid, name
FROM tu_tabla
```

Comment: Hola; no cambiar el orden, lo que se quiere es copiar los valores de una columna a otra ...